# RC and RH connector on Thermostat

Tags: hvac

I have an Air handler for AC in attic and Boiler in Basement.

Recently, HVAC technician came and saw that my thermostat had a jumper connecting RC to RH and removed it.

He connected RC to the attic unit and RH to the boiler, is this ok?

I'm wondering why it was connected with jumper in first place.

Comment: Our mindreader are not on duty today. What model is the thermostat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Furnace and A/C do not know the other exists. Really.

Standard American furnaces with ducts are modular systems. The furnace is just a furnace, though it has an "open source" air handling stack into which other modules can be added - HEPA filter, humidifier, ionizer, whatever floats your boat including air conditioner cooling grid.

So the furnace has a dog simple arrangement.  It has a 24 volt transformer (terminals R and C).  The gas solenoid valve is connected to C and W.  Then, R and W are brought up to a thermostat: Shorting R and W completes the circuit and provides a "call for heat" which the thermostat does at appropriate temperatures.  We're talking bang-bang controls here, so "bang" the furnace runs full blast to target temp, then "bang" the furnace shuts off.

The furnace's blower is under furnace control. It runs it when the exhaust/house air heat exchanger is warm enough.  As a convenience, the furnace also provides a "G" wire.  Shorting R to G forces the fan to run even though the furnace isn't heating.  *The furnace has no idea why it is running the fan; it's simply doing it because the thermostat shorted R and G.*

The A/C unit has its own control line called Y. If the thermostat shorts Y to ASTERISK HERE, then the A/C compressor unit starts up. The A/C compressor has no idea if if a furnace is involved, there could be a walk-in freezer or a water heater at the other end of that freon tubing.  It just pumps when Y is connected.

ASTERISK: We need a source of 24 volts to connect through Y to pick up the contactor. What do we do?

Now, the furnace's transformer has plenty of extra capacity.  So often, R and C are tapped by the A/C system.  R goes to the thermostat already; Y is run to the thermostat, and then C from the furnace is sent to the A/C unit to let it complete the circuit.  **In that case, the thermostat simply connects R to Y to call for A/C.**. Super simple wiring.

However, sometimes the A/C unit has its own transformer, so it makes its own R and C.  Now we have a nomenclature problem, because we have two R wires going to the thermostat.  It shouldn't hurt to cross them, but better not to.

So we call the furnace R "Rh", and the air conditioning R "Rc".

The thermostat keeps them separate internally: it connects W and G to Rh, and Y to Rc.

So, thermostats give you the option of jumpering Rh to RC, for use in the earlier mentioned case where the A/C simply borrows power from the furnace's transformer, and so, it's the same R wire.

Comment: and why was the Rc and the Rh bridged ?

Comment: @Ruskes Because either the previous furnace + AC only had one "R", and when everything was replaced nobody changed anything in the thermostat **or** the previous installer "always did it that way".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thank you, if you have shared (one) transformer then the Rh and Rc are bridged.

Comment: Thank you. The usage of the jumper didn't cause much harm since what I'm getting is that only a specific* combination of wires can trigger the heat or cold which is usually done by the thermostat?

Comment: @user159180 Yes, to call for cooling the thermostat shunts G to Rh to run the fan..... and Y to Rc to run the A/C compressor.  You have to shunt (short) each wire to the corresponding R, because connecting it to *the other one's* transformer will do nothing.  It'd be like taking hot from one generator and neutral from another generator.

Answer (score 0):

The tech did it right.

You have two separate units (Heating and Cooling)

Each has its own 24 volt transformer.

The Rh is for the heating controls.

while the Rc is for the cooling controls.

In case you have only one 24 V transformer for both units (rare) ,the Rh+Rc are bridged, so the thermostat can provide 24 V signal to each selected (heating (W) or Cooling (Y))

Comment: Thank you for answering.